# When the sentence exceeds a certain word, cut it off somewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, substr

I want a certain sentence interrupted when it exceeds a certain character limit, yes I used substr but it becomes ineffective when I use the if function

JS

```js
$(function () {
  $.getJSON("/admin/getposts", function (data) {
    $(".postsMain").empty();
    $.each(data.reverse(), function (v, veri) {
    let item = veri.data
    let content = item.content
    if(content > 70) {
    const generalContent = content.set((content).substr(0,110)+"...Devamını paylaşımda oku!")
  } 
     
  console.log("Data girdi") 
  $(".postsMain").append(`<div class="postsAlt">
<h3>${item.title}</h3><p class="aciklama">${content}</p>
<br /><p class="paylasimci">Paylaşan: ${item.sharer}</p><p class="tarih">Paylaşma zamanı: ${item.date}</p><button class="gitmeButton"><a class="git" href="https://endorfintr-blog.glitch.me/posts/${veri.ID}">Gönderiye git!</a></button></div>`);
  console.log('Başarıyla data çekildi'); 

});
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `content.set`? Did you mean `content.length > 70`? Why are you using an `if` statement to begin with? `if` is not a function. Do not use [`substr`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) — it’s deprecated.

Comment: Start by indenting your code properly...?

Comment: There are many answers on SO related to your question. Your title and description are asking for conflicting things. Are you truncating based on char count or word count? The split(), substring() and length methods give you what you need to achieve either. Have you looked at these? Your sample code is extraneous and doesn't provide a clear minimal reproducible example. We can't see the shape of your data and all the markup is unnecessary. Just provide a clear test case (starting string) and then what the truncated result should be so we can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming the question is that you want to cut the sentence of after the final word, after the character limit. So if the character limit is 10 and the sentence is "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" it cuts it of after lorem ipsum. If my understanding of the question is incorrect, tell me and i will delete the answer.

I would start by defining word limit

```
var wordlimit = 110;
```

Then make a substring with everything after that

```
var originalSentence = "some form of sentence.";
var endOfSentence = originalSentence.substring(wordlimit,originalSentence.length);
```

Then i would find out how many characters until next whitespace

```
var charactersUntilNextWord = endOfSentence.indexOf(" ");
```

Then i would add that to the wordlimit and make a new sentence with new wordlimit.

```
wordlimit = wordlimit+charactersUntilNextWord;
var newSentence = originalSentence.substring(0,wordlimit);
```

I hope this helps. If you are instead looking to cut the sentence after a certain number of words i would advise you to split the sentence on whitespace (" ") and then add all the words until that wordlimit to a new string.

Comment: Okay, but some contents are is smaller than 150 character. but it still substring.

Comment: Now i don't understand. If you don't want sentences with less than 150 characters to substring you put the wordlimit to 150 instead of 110. 

But if you want strings longer than 150 to be 110 long and all other strings to be ignored, just put if(content>150){  (substring code here...)  } instead of if(content>70)